# Сортировка новостей по дате

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите как на битриксе добавить подразделы в новостях c названием года и чтобы при нажатии на год выводились все новости за этот год.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
// выборка активных элементов из информационного блока 
// дата начала автивности старше 1 января 2003 года
// выбранные элементы будут сгруппированы по дате активности
$arFilter = Array(
   "IBLOCK_ID"=>2, // твой id блока
   ">DATE_ACTIVE_FROM"=>date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CLang::GetDateFormat("SHORT")), mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2003)), 
   "ACTIVE"=>"Y", 
   "!PROPERTY_SRC"=>false
   );
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("SORT"=>"ASC", "PROPERTY_PRIORITY"=>"ASC"), $arFilter, Array("DATE_ACTIVE_FROM"));
while($ar_fields = $res->GetNext())
{
  echo $ar_fields["DATE_ACTIVE_FROM"].": ".$ar_fields["CNT"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

А так имеется документация в котором можно найти все интересующие вопросы, главное понять как с ним работать. **bitrix api** - 
[link text](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/index.php)